# What is the maximum size of a cookie, and how many can be stored in a browser for each web site?

Tags: web-development, cookies, www

I am learning about cookies, and I wonder about browser support:

- For each domain/web site, how many cookies may be sent to a browser, and of what size?
- If multiple cookies are sent and stored, does that affect performance?

Comment: it's fine where it is; we now have two versions, one for SU (browser exe info) and one for SO (programmery info) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093793/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-cookie-and-how-many-can-be-stored-in-a-browser-for

Answer (score 11):

Different browsers have different size limits on cookies. Some [general guidelines](http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=13):

> Most of the documentation I've found (and there isn’t much) suggests that web browsers must support a minimum of:
>
> - 300 cookies in total
> - 20 cookies per domain
> - 4096 bytes per cookie
>
> It seems as though this minimum requirement is part of the [original RFC for cookies](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) – see section 6.3 specifically.

A page that lists the [actual in-practice cookie limits for several browsers](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/08/16/browser-cookie-limits/):

> #### Per Domain Cookie Limit
>
> Here is a [test script to test your browser](http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/javascript/maximum-cookies/):
>
> - Firefox 2: 50<sup>1</sup>
> - Firefox 3: 50<sup>1</sup>
> - Internet Explorer 7<sup>2</sup>: 50 (after applying [a patch from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937143/))
> - Opera 9: 30
> - Safari: No Limit(!)
>
> #### Maximum Cookie Limit:
>
> - Firefox 2: 1000<sup>1</sup>
> - Firefox 3: 1000<sup>1</sup>
> - Internet Explorer: unknown
> - Opera: unknown

<sup>1</sup> can be [set](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.cookie.maxPerHost) between 0 and 65535
<sup>2</sup> documented by Microsoft [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306070)

Cookies are not saved on a server basis but on a *domain* basis (a server may host many domains or the opposite a server farm may be serving a single domain).

In general, I would avoid saving lots of information in cookies, as the data gets sent to and from the browser on every request. As you suggest in your question, this can have a effect on performance.

Usually one stores small amounts of data in the cookie, mostly used to identify the user/session so more data can be picked up from a database or another resource local to the web server.

Comment: Cookies are quite unreliable as a state-preserving tool, because browser settings may block cookies from some or all domains.

Comment: [Here is a test page](http://myownplayground.atspace.com/cookietest.html) containing many of the latest browser limits. Some have moved on since this was written.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research I recommend you use no more than 50 cookies, and no more than 4093 bytes for all cookies per domain.

The lowest common denominator is:

- IE 8/9/10/11 have a limit of **50 cookies**, 5117 characters per cookie, and 10234 bytes per domain
- Safari ?? on iPad iOS 5.1 have a limit of 600 cookies, 4093 bytes per cookie, and **4093 bytes per domain**

Out of interest, notice that IE has a *character* limit while most have a *byte* limit. This means for multi-byte encodings like UTF-8 IE can fit in more data.

You can read more here: http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/